# JMX Defined

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jmx

I am looking for:

- What JMX is.
- Where I can find some good JMX
  Tutorials.
- What JMX can provide to me as a
  Java EE programmer.
- Anything else I should be    aware
  of.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

JMX is a way to view and manipulate the runtime state of your application.  It's somewhat similar in concept to SNMP, if that helps.  IMO, it's indispensable for monitoring and understanding server-type applications that might not have any other user interface besides writing to a log file.

The basic approach is to create an interface for the things you want to monitor, then have a class implement the interface, then register an instance of that class with the "MBeanServer" (which actually makes the stuff defined in the interface available to JMX monitoring apps like jconsole).

Here's a trivial -- but working -- example:

(I'm assuming Java 5 or better)

### TestServerMBean.java

```
public interface TestServerMBean
{
    public long getUptimeMillis();
    public long getFooCount();
    public void setFooCount(long val);
    public void printStuff(String stuff);
}
```

### TestServer.java:

```
import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;

import javax.management.ObjectName;

// If jconsole doesn't see this app automatically, invoke the application with the following java flags, and connect
// 'remotely' via jconsole.
//
// -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
// -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=2222 (or whatever)
// -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
// -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
public class TestServer implements TestServerMBean
{
    private final AtomicLong m_counter = new AtomicLong(0L);
    private final long m_startTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();

    public void run() throws InterruptedException {
        while (true) {
            m_counter.incrementAndGet();
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        }
    }

    public long getFooCount() {
        return m_counter.get();
    }

    public void setFooCount(long val) {
        m_counter.set(val);
    }

    public long getUptimeMillis() {
        return System.currentTimeMillis() - m_startTimeMillis;
    }

    public void printStuff(String stuff) {
        System.out.println(stuff);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        TestServer ts = new TestServer();
        ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer().registerMBean(ts, new ObjectName("myapp:service=MyServer"));
        ts.run();
    }
}
```

Compile and run TestServer.class as usual, fire up `jconsole`, connect to TestServer (it'll show up automatically, else see comments in code above), then look at the 'MBeans' tab, and you'll see our instance named `myapp:service=MyServer`.  You can view the current "uptime", and watch `FooCounter` increment every 5 seconds.  You can also set FooCounter to whatever (long) value you want, and invoke the `printStuff` method with any String argument.

Obviously this is a ridiculous "server", but hopefully having a simple working example will help illustrate the overall concept: being able to peek into and manipulate a running app.

There are a lot of additional features and different types of MBeans, but just the vanilla JMX shown above goes a long way, IMO.

Comment: nice example yes, but it doesn't make anything visible in JConsole

Answer (score 14):

In a nutshell JMX allows you to remotely invoke methods or view exposed data from the inside of a running JVM. A lot of applications use JMX to sort of attach a remote dashboard to their running JVMs in order to provide remote management.

For example, if you had an app server running on a machine, with JMX it would be possible to remotely view the exposed information about that server. It is also possible to code your own JMX MBeans which can expose any variables or methods inside your application. The exposed variables can then be "polled" remotely to test for certain conditions you would like to know about.

Another useful thing about JMX is that you can remotely change variables on the fly. For instance, if you have some sort of pool set up that has a maximum total amount, this maximum amount can be changed remotely without having to restart or change any configuration files on your application server.

`jconsole` is provided by Sun with Java to be able to easily view your MBeans remotely without having to code your own client solution. You could also consume the MBeans with a custom solution which can give you excellent flexibility.

Also, there are already some monitoring software that come with JMX MBean monitoring built in. Zenoss and Applications Manager 8 do this, to name a couple.

**Addition:**

There is already a lot of software that takes advantage of JMX. Tomcat exposes information that is accessible via jconsole and so does JBoss Application Server.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe JSR 262 is also worth to be mentioned here.

"JSR 262 defines a connector for the JMX Remote API that uses Web Services to make JMX instrumentation available remotely. Clients do not have to be Java applications, but can be."

It is very likely that JSR 262 will be part of the next Java version (Java 7).

There is a java.net project for a [JMX WS connector](https://ws-jmx-connector.dev.java.net/) which depends on [WiseMan project](http://wiseman.dev.java.net/). Wiseman is an Open Source Java implementation of WS-Management standard.

Comment: Project link now is http://ws-jmx-connector.java.net/

Answer (score 1):

Here are some decent web resources:

- [Oracle JMX Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jmx/tutorial/tutorialTOC.html)
- [Java monitoring & management overview](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/management/overview.html)
- [JMX in Action (available as an eBook)](http://www.manning.com/sullins/)

Answer (score 0):

These are the two I read when first reading up on JMX.

Sun Tutorial: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/jmx/index.html

Spring 2.5/JMX: http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/jmx.html

Answer (score 0):

Or you can go see the [JMX tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jmx/info) right here on StackOverflow, I updated it a few days ago to list pretty much what you asked for, and some contributed additional info:

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jmx/info

Comment: I posted this question 3 years ago.. I'm pretty sure that didn't exist

Comment: @dubdubdubdot: Tag wiki existed, but the content in there was either empty or different.

Comment: Having worked on this technology for around 4 years, I presented this session few years back about "Introduction to Java Management Extensions (JMX)" at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F-f2zYeWwwo. Slides for this session are available at http://www.slideshare.net/tarun.telang/java-management-extensions-jmx.